# Count each node number of parents in a tree graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am pretty new to Cypher.

I have a hierarchical tree built in NEO4J, and I need to set a "depth" property on each node, which would contains its number of parents. Is there a single cypher query that could set/update those properties ?

```
     a
    / \
   b   c
  / \
 d   e
```

So in this tree, a.depth = 0, b.depth = 1, c.depth =1, d.depth = 2, e.depth = 2, and so on...

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the path a variable and use its length:

```
 MATCH p=(a:MyLabel {key:''value'})-[*..20]->(x)
 SET x.depth = length(p)
```

Comment: You've got the answer, but you should edit to provide the answer - this doesn't set a depth on OP's nodes or explain the connection between depth and length

Comment: Hey OP, one other point here - this assumes you have a well-behaved tree.  If you have cycles in your tree or it's otherwise not a tree, this method will not work correctly.  So make sure your data is clean and actually represents a hierarchy.

Comment: in case of a non well formed tree adding the `shortestPath` function might help.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits : yup, well form tree indeed.

Comment: That works thanks. I'm adding another way I found just in case it helps someone. Performance are the same with my data....

Answer (score 0):

Stefan's answer works great, but here is another way I found:

```
MATCH (a:MyLabel)<-[r:*..20]-(parent:MyLabel)
WITH a, count(r) AS parents
SET a.depth = parents
```

Not faster with my data, kind of the same performance on a few hundreds of nodes.